# Icon rotates but goes back to previous position

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `Bootstraps` accordion element and when it opens I want to rotate the icon. I use `jQuery` to check if it's collapsed or not (so other elements would close) and right then I want to rotate the icon. 
I add a class using `jQuery` that rotates the icon (which works) but it jumps back to how it was before:

```
.cross_up{
        background:url(../img/cross.png) center center;
        transition: all 0.20s ease;
    }

    .cross_down{
        transition: all 0.20s ease;
        transform:rotate(45deg);
        animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    }
```

HTML

```
<span class="cross_up"> </span>Verzekeringen
```

jQuery

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".cross_up").addClass("cross_down");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".cross_down").removeClass("cross_down");
});
```

Working link [here](http://speyer.clouddesign.be/diensten.php)

Comment: could you provide a working demo of the issue?

Comment: @jbutler483 Link added

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? To prevent the icon from rotating back?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want it to rotate 45deg and stay like that, until it's not closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because of background you are trying to rotate. You should try to rotate the whole span.

```
<span class= "cross_down">
<span class="cross_up"> </span> 
</span>
Verzekeringen
```

Refer link if you want to apply css transform on background images.

http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/

Comment: Did you try adding that image by img tag, rather than a background image? And i think animation-fill-mode property doesn't need here.

Comment: Ah yes, the img tag does indeed work. Thanks, the refer link was interesting too.